# How to plot average of values for a year

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a data frame like so. I am trying to make a plot with the mean of 'number' for each year on the y and the year on the x. I think what I have to do to do this is make a new data frame with 2 columns 'year' and 'avg number' for each year. How would I go about doing that?

```
    year    number  
0   2010    40  
1   2010    44
2   2011    33  
3   2011    32  
4   2012    34 
5   2012    56
```

Comment: `df.groupby('year')['number'].mean().plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

When opening a question about pandas please make sure you following these guidelines: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). It will help us reproduce your environment.

Assuming your dataframe is stored in the `df` variable:

```py
df.groupby('year').mean().plot()
```